# Building a Matrix as a piecewise-function of the indices without for loops

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, sparse-arrays, procedural-programming

I'm very new to Mathematica and this site. I've read that building matrices with For loops is slow, and I have experienced this myself on the current project. I'm trying to wrap my head around building matrices according to complicated rules without nested loops. I have a specific example I'm stuck on but I'm also looking for general tips for approaching the problem. My background is not in computer science, so some of the explanations I have found on this site and elsewhere are a bit hard for me to follow. For example, discussions of functional programming baffle me.

Things I've been reading about:

- MapIndexed, Apply, Span
- Transformation rules (for example, I tried building a table of rules and then using that to build the matrix) and Associations
- The matrices involved can be quite large and are almost entirely 0, so I have been able to use SparesArrays with relatively simple rules on everything except the example below.
- The matrix I care about for this question exhibits a lot of nice symmetries; except near the corners, it is constant along these diagonal bands and 'reflected' about the main diagonal. Thus, I experimented with the Band command as well.

The one I'm stuck on is below. The value of the [[i,j]] entry is a function if i and j in a sort of complicated way. But in general I'm not sure I understand how mathematica builds up complicated matrices.

Here's the definition of jacobW, the matrix I need, that currently produces the correct values for all the parameters I've tried; it's just very slow.

```
jacobW = ConstantArray[0, {L, L}];
For[
    i = firstIndex, i <= lastIndex, i++,
    For[
        j = firstIndex, j <= lastIndex, j++,
        Which[
                j < i - r, jacobW[[i, j]] = 0,
                j >= i - r && j <= i + r, 
     jacobW[[i, j]] = 
      h/2*((jacobU[[i - r, j]] - jacobU[[i, j]])*
           mu[X[[i - r]] - X[[i]]] + (jacobU[[i + r, j]] - 
             jacobU[[i, j]])*mu[X[[i + r]] - X[[i]]]) + 
       h*Sum[mu[
           X[[i + l]] - X[[i]]]*(jacobU[[i + l, j]] - 
            jacobU[[i, j]]), {l, 1 - r, r - 1}],
                j > i + r, jacobW[[i, j]] = 0   
            ];
        ];
    ];
```

Here, X is a list of evenly spaced real numbers like

```
X=Range[.1 , 1.1 , 0.0333333]
```

In general mu is a more complicated function but you can take it to be mu(z)=z for the sake of simplicity. You might be able to just take jacobU to be the identity; if you want something closer to what it really looks like I included it's ArrayRules below.

```
{{1, 1} -> 1, {1, 4} -> 2, {1, 7} -> -1, {2, 4} -> 
  2, {2, 6} -> -1, {2, 2} -> 1, {3, 4} -> 2, {3, 5} -> -1, {3, 3} -> 
  1, {4, 4} -> 1, {5, 5} -> 1, {6, 6} -> 1, {7, 7} -> 1, {8, 8} -> 
  1, {9, 9} -> 1, {10, 10} -> 1, {11, 11} -> 1, {12, 12} -> 
  1, {13, 13} -> 1, {14, 14} -> 1, {15, 15} -> 1, {16, 16} -> 
  1, {17, 17} -> 1, {18, 18} -> 1, {19, 19} -> 1, {20, 20} -> 
  1, {21, 21} -> 1, {22, 22} -> 1, {23, 23} -> 1, {24, 24} -> 
  1, {25, 25} -> 1, {26, 26} -> 1, {27, 27} -> 1, {28, 28} -> 
  1, {29, 29} -> 1, {30, 30} -> 1, {31, 31} -> 1, {32, 32} -> 
  1, {33, 33} -> 1, {34, 34} -> 1, {35, 33} -> -1, {35, 35} -> 
  1, {35, 34} -> 2, {36, 32} -> -1, {36, 34} -> 2, {36, 36} -> 
  1, {37, 34} -> 2, {37, 37} -> 1, {37, 31} -> -1, {_, _} -> 0}
```

I expect jacobW to have this sort of banded structure:[image: banded matrix, jacobW]

I'd be okay if you don't give me a solution, but rather some tips on how to think about the problem. Something about it is breaking my brain. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should take a look at `SparseArray`

Comment: @MarcoB I did say "The matrices involved can be quite large and are almost entirely 0, so I have been able to use SparesArrays with relatively simple rules on everything except the example below." My issue here is that I do not see how to convert the loop above into a list of rules that I can plug into SparseArray. What would that look like for something like this?

Comment: welcome to MMA and MMA SE! there's a problem I see in the `For` loop: when `i == r` and `j` is in bounds (e.g. `i == j == r == 2`) you wind up taking `X[[0]]` and `jacobU[[0, j]]`. Is this meant to be excluded somehow? mathematica lists are `1`-indexed, so I'm surprised this is working!

Comment: also, more simply than for loops, in general try `Table[f[i,j], {i, i0, i1}, {j, j0, j1}]` and `Array[f, {idim, jdim}]`. you'll still probably want something different for this particular problem, but it's much easier notation to use as a "first attempt" in Mathematica, and in general `Array` and `Table` are the basic ways to build up lists/matrices! also note you can simply do `Range[.1, 1.1, 1/30]`, and the machine-number quality of the bounds will cause `1/30` to be converted to machine precision automatically.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked it. Can you *describe* the rules that you use in your loops? It's be faster than us trying to reconstruct them through your code. Also, the picture of the final matrix contains numerical values, so its hard to infer the structure that generated it.

Comment: @thorimur thanks for that input. Can you clarify a bit more what you think the index issue is in the For loop? I think I only half understand what you're saying there.
Originally what is now "r" was actually an entry from some other vector, but I realized I can assume it's constant and it didn't break the code. I admit I have not thought about the issue you mention before.

I have used Arrays and Tables elsewhere, but not here. And the 0.033 was just because of the way I copy/pasted into stack exchange, that constant is handled differently in the actual code. But thank you for that tip

Comment: @MarcoB you're right, it's a bit hard to see what's going on from your end. Both jacobU and jacobW are matrices whose entries correspond to the partial derivatives of some function. The [i,j] entry of jacobU is the partial derivative of u_i with respect to u_j at the specific point I care about. In general, the u's are independent: most of the entries are 0 and the main diagonal is all 1s. Near the corners though, the u's are linear combinations of each other, with coefficients 1,-1, or 2 depending on their relative positions. Then each w_i depends on the u_i's according to the formula pasted

Comment: @Bill I see now what you mean: no reason to reassign the entries that are 0 since I initialized them that way already. So we only need to worry about the nonzero entries, meaning we can reduce the indices we are looping over. This is a good tip, and I appreciate it, but I was hoping to do away with the loop structure entirely.

Comment: hmm. maybe it's because of `firstIndex` and `lastIndex`? those seem like they must depend on `r` somehow for this to work; otherwise, try to evaluate the nontrivial bit with `i = 2; j = 2; r = 2`, and you'll get an error (or something non-numeric)

Comment: yeah I think firstIndex should always be strictly greater than r and last index will be less than L-r, where L is the dimension of the matrix. I'm on a different device right now so I can't test the code but I can try that out.

Comment: cool! observation: if `X` really is always a range of evenly-spaced numbers, then the list of derived quantities used in each calculation—`{X[[i - r]] - X[[i]], X[[i - r + 1]] - X[[i]], ... X[[i + r]] - X[[i]]}`—is actually independent of `i`! this means you can compute it beforehand, apply `mu` to it once, halve the values at either end and multiply by `h`, and then use a dot product with an appropriate sublist taken from `jacobU` at an `i,j` dependent position. not a fully formed approach yet, but it might help...

Comment: (also, just for the general vibe to go for, since you asked for tips on how to think about the problem: things will generally be quicker if you can do "less things twice" and "more things at once". so, if you can figure out a way to precompute as much as possible and just reuse it, and then use whole-matrix operations (or `Band` ones, as you mentioned, or `Map`ped ones) rather than individual-entry ones, things will likely be quicker. if you have the computer memory, it might be the case that you can more quickly work with the whole `jacobU` matrix, and shifted versions of it, at once.)

Comment: I stopped thinking about this exactly in the moment when I realized that the code cannot be executed because most of the symbols are undefined.